# Select all Sheet from an Excel File

Tags: excel, dataset

basically, i am uplaoding a dynamic excel file  and i want to select all the sheets containing a data and have it in a dataset. But i dont know how, all I can get is from a static sheet name and only one sheet per select, how can i select all shhet within one excel file and have it in a dataset? thanks.

this is what i got so far

```
Dim exConS As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                        excelfile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
Dim exCon As New OleDbConnection(exConS)
Dim dsExcel As New DataSet()
Dim sExcel As String = "SELECT * FROM [SSI-data3$]"
Dim daExcel As New OleDbDataAdapter(sExcel, exCon)
daExcel.Fill(dsExcel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135981.aspx) with suitable schema name from the [Jet schema set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668764.aspx) to retrieve the names of tables - in Excel, this includes both named ranges and sheets.

You would have to create a UNION query to get every sheet in the one set of data, which would only be suitable if the columns matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to get worksheet names and then with a `foreach` you can get them